# Stream video to VM as virtual camera input using gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, vlc, v4l2loopback

I stream my camera from a PC to a remote VM using VLC.

`cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 :live-caching=300 :sout="#transcode{vcodec=FLV1,scale=0.75,vb=128,acodec=none}:http{dst=:8080/stream.wmv}"`

I can see the camera from the VM with port forwarding (`ssh -C -X -p 22 user@83.*.*.* -R 8080:localhost:80`) and with this command:

`wget http://13.*.*.*:8080/stream.wmv -O - | mplayer mplayer -cache 8192 -`

I would like to take that stream and send it to a virtual camera, lets say /dev/video9. This virtual camera should be readable from Skype.
For the virtual camera I use v4l2loopback. In order to receive the stream I use gstreamer and mjpegtools_yuv_to_v4l.

I have read from 
[How can I use vloopback mjpeg pipe without WebcamStudio][1]
something like this:

`gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=http://13*.*.*.*:8080/stream.wmv ! decodebin ! y4menc ! filesink location=output.yuv & cat output.yuv | mjpegtools_yuv_to_v4l /dev/video9`

but I get errors like

sfdemux0: Could not demultiplex stream.
Additional debug info:
EOF in read stream header, stop.

Thank you.